# Disable specific dates and times on react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, calendar, frontend

I am working on a *Agenda-like* RN App. This specific component receives from the backend an array of weekdays/times that are going to be available to add an Event. Moreover, it receives an array of previously added events. The structure is similar to this:

**Event**

```js
{
    title: string,
    date: date
    start_time: time,
    end_time: time
}
```

**Available times**

```js
{
    weekday: number,
    start_time: time,
    end_time: time
}
```

I would like to block every weekday that is not an available weekday (e.g. block all sundays and wednesdays). Also, I want to block the times that are out of the available time range and/or were taken by an event.

Any idea how would I do that? I am using the react-native-community/datetimepicker, but if it is not possible to do with that, I am fully open to other solutions

Comment: I believe this is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. If you already have a solution you are trying but are experiencing a specific problem, post your code and you'll probably get some help figuring out what went wrong.